# How to optimize loading data into a treeview

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, treeview

I want to optimize the loading time for several treeviews in VB.NET application. The structure of each treeview is based on a database table whose information is represented by a dataset. 
Each table has an ID and an Parent_ID, which means each table contains a hierarchical strucuture. For this reason it is necessary to populate each treeview by using code that helps creating the correct structure.

```
Private Function setTreenodeCollection(ByRef inDataset As DataSet, _
                                        ByVal tblName As String, _
                                        Optional ByVal inUseCheckboxes As Boolean = True)
    Dim resultSet As New TreeNodeCollection
    Dim nodes As New List(Of cls_TreeNode_Exp)
    If Not dr.RowState = DataRowState.Deleted And dr("Description", DataRowVersion.Original).ToString.Length > 0 Then
    Dim NodeAkt As cls_TreeNode_Exp = New cls_TreeNode_Exp(dr, dr("Description"), dr("ID"), typ, inUseCheckboxes, icon)
    nodes.Add(NodeAkt)

    Dim childNodes As List(Of cls_TreeNode_Exp) = (From node As cls_TreeNode_Exp In nodes
                                                        Where node.DR("ID_parent") = 0
                                                        Select node).ToList

    For Each node As cls_TreeNode_Exp In childNodes
        nodes.Remove(node)
        resultSet.Add(node)

        Me.getChildNodes(nodes, node)
    Next

    Return resultSet
End Function


Private Sub getChildNodes(inNodes As List(Of cls_TreeNode_Exp), inParentNode As cls_TreeNode_Exp)
    Dim childNodes As List(Of cls_TreeNode_Exp)

    childNodes = (From node As cls_TreeNode_Exp In inNodes
                  Where node.DR("ID_parent") = inParentNode.DR("ID")
                  Select node).ToList

    For Each node As cls_TreeNode_Exp In childNodes
        inNodes.Remove(node)
        inParentNode.Nodes.Add(node)

        Me.getChildNodes(inNodes, node)
    Next
End Sub
```

Depending on the table there migth be up to 10000 results which end up being added nodes. Each node has its corresponding datarow attached to it via the field "DR". How can I speed this up without doing a major refactoring?

Comment: Is the process slow?  Are you timing specific parts of it to find out which code block is the slow part?

Comment: As soon as nodes has a the the list "nodes" in setTreenodeCollection gets a high amount of entries it gets really slow in general. But imo it's the procedure whichs determines the childnodes that is the core of the problem.

Comment: If you are loading nodes, why are you removing them, too?

Comment: They are being removed from the parents list and added to the childs list if the criteria are met. This is not my own code, it's taken from an older application which is still in use by some customers and since it's dev left and there is practically no documentation I have to fix this somehow. This problem startet emerging when some tables grew in matters of their rownumber and now the application can't be used properly.

Answer (score 0):

Populating a tree-view up front can be a VERY long task ... especially if there is some depth to the tree nodes.

A better method is to dynamically populate as you go.

Populate only the root level and add a single, appropriately identified dummy child to each node if that node has children. 
Then use the before expand event on the node to populate the children on demand using the same method to place markers for any subsequent children. Remembering to delete the dummy child.

It adds a little overhead to opening the nodes you have not populated yet, but if that node does not contain 1,000s of children it should not be a significant delay. If it does.. a treeview probably isn't the right control to be using.

Tip: You can use the nodes tag property to help simplify the expand event... For example, you could have it contain the required SQL query you need to run to populate the node.

ALSO : Always use the suspend and resume layout properties when updating such controls.